# Is there an app/extension similar to The Great Suspender but for Safari?

Tags: safari, macos, imac

Safari is sucking wind lately, for me. I have a new 1TB hard drive in my system, put in Jan 2016. For Chrome I use Great Suspender extension - it halts tabs/sites after not being used for a while. Anything similar to this for Safari? Or any other suggestions to get Safari nice and zippy again? Thx.

Comment: Which version of Safari and which version of OSX are you using?

Comment: Thanks for responding. @AlistairMcMillan I am using:Safari Version 9.1 (11601.5.17.1) El Capitan 10.11.4 (15E65)

Comment: https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.Vocab7.thesuspender-QMHYRDLA7A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari Extension called The Suspender by Brian Watkins

https://utahbrian.com/the-suspender/

Comment: That is great! Well done! When will it be available?

Comment: Scratch that! I see it is already there. I will give it a whirl. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like it might not be maintained very well, but that sure would be great.

Comment: The website is broken now.

Comment: The only working alternative as of now seems to be https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tab-suspender-for-safari/id1495356253

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. There are only a few utilities for listing tabs in different ways, but nothing like The Great Suspender as of the end of 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not the same thing, but check out "Sessions". You can save tabs, and later on restore them.

Answer (score 0):

Safari now has this built-in but the default is that the feature is disabled. To enable it:

1. Exit Safari
2. run this command in terminal to enable Safari's debug mode

   `defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu -bool YES`
3. Open Safari and de-select **Debug** > **Miscellaneous Flags** > **Disable Background Tab Suspension**

Source: MacRumors' forum  "[Does safari put inactive tabs to sleep?](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/does-safari-put-inactive-tabs-to-sleep.2330842/)"